# Magento htaccess Rewrite and Redirect

Tags: regex, .htaccess, magento

On a Magento based ecommerce site I am trying to remove index.php from URLs as well as 301 redirect non-www to www.

Default URL: www.example.com/index.php/super-cool-product.html

Desired Product URL: www.example.com/super-cool-product.html

Also 301 redirecting non-www to www:
example.com/super-cool-product.html
to:
www.example.com/super-cool-product.html

As well as:
www.example.com/index.html
to:
www.example.com

This is what I currently have:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ http://www.rejuvahealth.com/$1 [R=301,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index.html
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.html$ http://www.rejuvahealth.com/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

Comment: You don't say what is wrong so I assume what you have done is working. Well done on your success!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To 301 redirect index.html:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
redirect 301 /index.html http://www.example.co.uk/
```

If you configure your Base URLs correctly, Magento should automatically redirect to the www. version.

For index.php rewrites, go to **Configuration > Web > Use Web Server Rewrites** and change to 'Yes'.

Now open your htaccess and change this line:

```
#RewriteBase /magento/
```

to this:

```
RewriteBase /
```

Assuming that your Magento folder is on the root. Be careful when using web rewrites though and ensure you back up before making any changes.

Comment: I couldn't get this to work: `redirect 301 /index.html http://www.example.co.uk/` But found it can be set by going to `Catalog > URL Rewrite Management` Thank you for your help!